# Reinvoking the constructor of a statically allocated object

Tags: c++

I have an object that was statically allocated. This object does not have `operator=` and I needed to reconstruct it.

So, this does **not** work for me:

```
myObj = T(...);
```

My current approach is:

```
myObj.~T()
new(&myObj) T(...);
```

But it feels wrong, so I was wondering if there is any pitfall that I am missing here.

Comment: This is the way to do it, if you really  must. But IMO the problem is the design decision that lead you to having to do this. Can't you have a member function like `reset()` or something?

Comment: *How* was it statically allocated? `const`-qualified?

Comment: You could have a static unique_ptr instead and allocate a new object in the pointer.

Comment: If the `new` throws, then the object will not exist, giving undefined behaviour when it's destroyed automatically at the end of the program.

Comment: Obviously, the constructor does something which you want to be done twice (or more often). Your question is too vague for a concrete solution, but your long-term goal to fix this problem should be to move the functionality out of the constructor, into a normal function which can be called as often as you wish. Attempts to reinvoke a constructor is nothing but fixing symptoms of a design problem.

Answer (score 1):

If an object was statically allocated and you would want to reallocate it without resorting to UB, the best bet is to take control of the scope and decide

1. When by latest you can wait until you should allocate the object
2. When by earliest you should free the object

To understand it better let us consider an example

```
void foo()
{
    {
    Foo obj(...); // obj gets allocated
    // Code which uses obj
    } // obj gets automatically de-allocated
    {
    Foo obj; // obj gets allocated (default constructed)
    // Code which uses obj
    } // obj gets automatically de-allocated
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the object as a [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) and you can now recreate it at will.  Just remember to make sure it exists before using it each time.

`boost` also has such a class, and in my experience you can roll your own optional as well.